# Bounded Variation and Continuity

Tags: continuity, bounded-variation

Let $f$ be of bounded variation on $\mathbb{R}$. Let
$$
V_{f}(x)=V(f ;-\infty, x)
$$
Prove that $f$ is continuous at $c$ if and only if $V_{f}$ is continuous at $c$.

**Update**: $V(f ;-\infty, c)=\sup \{V(f: a, b):[a, b] \subset(-\infty, c]\}$

It seems that the proof for continuity of function $f$ at closed interval $[a,b]$ can't be applied for the interval $(-\infty, x)$, and requires other techniques to be implemented. Are there any suggestions on proving this continuity property?! Maybe, dividing into two cases of RHS & LHS limit, along with gauging the mesh of partition?!

Comment: How do you define $V(f;-\infty,x)$.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Thank you for mentioning the definition of that term. I modified the part with the correct definition of it.

Comment: Maybe use the additive property of variation? Pick a point $a \lt x$ and then variation is a constant plus variation on $[a, x]$

Comment: @TomCollinge Could you please verify with more rigor how the division of the interval could help you to assist in solving the problem?!

Comment: From your comments in the problem, you presumably have the result for a closed interval. It's late here, I'll look at this again tomorrow.

Comment: Are there any further comments or ideas regarding the problem?

Comment: @TomCollinge Can you give any insights on how could it be proceeded?!

Comment: $V(f ;-\infty, x)$ is a constant $+ V(f ;a, x)$. So, $V(f ;-\infty, x)$ is continuous iff $+ V(f ;a, x)$ is continuous, which we know is continuous iff $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @TomCollinge Could you please elaborate on the part "$V(f; -\infty, x)$ is a constant $+V(f; a, x)$"? Did you mean that $V(f; -\infty, x)$ is decomposed of constant value and $V(f; a, x)$? If yes, how do you derive the fact that constant value could be separated?!

Comment: $V(f; -\infty, x) = V(f; -\infty, a) + V(f; a, x) = C + V(f; a, x)$